# ListFragment and menu options

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have added an options menu to a ListFragment, and I need to show a new ListFragment when  users click on it. Is there something wrong with this? I am a bit confused on the correct way to start fragment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Transaction with the FragmentManager.

Comment: Ya of course, but the question is a bit different.. when  I select an option in the menu, I invoke an callback which start the new listfragment.